# Difference between [Object, Object] and Array(2)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working in AngularJS and trying to send data to my backend.

I noticed that when the variable in my service has this structure `test = [Object, Object]` it gets passed into a `List<String>` in my ASP.NET backend, but i have trouble passing `test = Array(2)` into my backend.

I see the formats when i am debugging and set a breakpoint on the variable.

Is there a difference between the two? Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do here? just initialize an Array with the length == 2?

Comment: Obviously the one contains two functions while the other contains nothing.

Comment: Please show your real code and present your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: It would be hard to post the code as the arrays are created after a few service calls and some changes. @Dai comment explains what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first case:

```
var x = { foo: "bar", qux: 123 };
var y = { baz: "123", yeen: { arr: [1,2,3] };

var test = [ x, y ]; // [Object,Object]
```

For the second case, refer to MDN's documentation for `Array()`:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
>
> ```
> new Array(arrayLength)
> ```
>
> If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and `2^32 - 1` (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with its length property set to that number

So your second case code presumably is:

```
var test = Array(2);
```

...this actually evaluates to `[undefined,undefined]`), however .NET (thus ASP.NET) does not have a concept of "`undefined`" (compared to `null`), so this value is not serializable to JSON (as JSON does not allow `undefined` values) - so this explains why it's failing.

If an "empty" array element is meaningful in your application you should use explicit `null` values instead - ideally using an array-literal like so:

```
var ret = [ null, null ];
```

Or if the number of elements is variable:

```
var ret = Array( 123 ); // This creates a 123-sized array, where every element is undefined. This cannot be serialized to JSON
ret.fill( null );       // This explicitly sets every element to a null value. The array can now be serialized to JSON.
```

Comment: Thanks @Dai, I was able to trace it and find that ASP.NET was dropping some empty arrays and so it was giving me errors.

Comment: The array literal equivalent of `Array(2)` is `[,,]`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Good catch - I've amended my answer.